# Chromecast session status returns undefined on Chrome mobile iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile, google-cast

Chromecast session status returns undefined on Chrome mobile ios. The session exists and has other properties defined, like sessionID. On the desktop, the session status returns "connected", "disconnected", or "stopped" as expected. Is this a bug with Chrome ios? Is there another way to detect the session status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which seems to be sufficient for my needs.

My setup for getting the session.status:

```
// create var to store 'fake' status
var fakeStatus = 'none';

// returns 'none' if no session exists 
// else returns session.status
// else if session.status is undefined && media.playerState exists return forceStatus
castplayer.getSessionStatus = function(){ 
    return session?(session.status===undefined&&this.currentMedia.playerState?fakeStatus:session.status):'none'
};
```

Updating fakeStatus when session is created on chrome.cast.initialize:

```
var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest, sessionListener, receiverListener);
chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onInitError);

function sessionListener(e){
    session = e;
    fakeStatus = 'connected';
    ...
};
```

Updating fakeStatus with session's update listener:

```
chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSuccess, onRequestError);

function onRequestSuccess(e) {
    session = e;
    session.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
    ...
};

function updateListener(isAlive) {
    if(isAlive) fakeStatus = 'connected'; else fakeStatus = 'disconnected';
    ...
};
```

Making sure to set fakeSatus to 'none' and null out the session on stop error:

```
session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onStopAppError);

function onStopAppError(e) {
    fakeStatus = 'none';
    session = null;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on iOS and Android are not supported by Cast SDK.

Comment: Actually, I think they are. ios: [link](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2014/07/chrome-for-ios-update.html)

Comment: No, Cast SDK is not supported on those platforms.

Comment: Then I wonder why Chrome mobile update release notes say, "Allows mobile sites that have added Cast support to work with your Cast-enabled device" if the Cast SDK doesn't support it? It doesn't make any sense. The cast javascript does seem to work except for some issues like this.